# How to find the maximum value in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list with ~10^6 tuples in it like this:

```
[(101, 153), (255, 827), (361, 961), ...]
  ^     ^
  X     Y
```

I want to find the maximum value of the `Y`s in this list, but also want to know the `X` that it is bound to.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`operator.itemgetter()`:

```
In [53]: lis=[(101, 153), (255, 827), (361, 961)]

In [81]: from operator import itemgetter

In [82]: max(lis, key=itemgetter(1))  # Faster solution
Out[82]: (361, 961)

In [83]: max(lis, key=itemgetter(1))[0]  # Faster solution
Out[83]: 361
```

`lambda`:

```
In [54]: max(lis, key=lambda item: item[1])
Out[54]: (361, 961)

In [55]: max(lis, key=lambda item: item[1])[0]
Out[55]: 361
```

`timeit` comparison of `operator.itemgetter` vs `lambda`:

```
In [84]: %timeit max(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 232 us per loop

In [85]: %timeit max(lis, key=lambda item: item[1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 556 us per loop
```

Comment: (+1) would `operator.itemgetter(1)` would work better than the lambda in this case because the lambda would get created for each of the 10**6 times.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: is there a considerable speed difference between `operator.itemgetter` and `lambda` in such cases, though?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, `itemgetter` is about twice as fast according to a quick test I did. However, it doesn't have anything to do with creating the function multiple times as you say in your first comment. A predefined pure python function that does the same thing as `lambda x: x[1]` performs at the same speed. I assume that `itemgetter` does some of its work at c speed.

Comment: @senderle That's strange, [my timings](http://pastebin.com/u80nNYg0) show that `lambda` is in 17% faster than `itemgetter` in this case. Why did we get so different results?

Comment: @lazyr i think you should use `max(lis,key=itemgetter(1))`, not `max(lis,itemgetter(1))
`
`

Comment: +1, but two minor nits: I'd put the `itemgetter` solution first instead of second (it's more Pythonic, simpler, and faster…), and I'd use a different variable name instead of `x` (since the OP is referring to his tuples as `(x, y)`, so it could be potentially confusing to call the whole thing `x`).

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary How to use timeit in standard python file?

Answer (score 14):

In addition to max, you can also sort:

```
>>> lis
[(101, 153), (255, 827), (361, 961)]
>>> sorted(lis,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
(361, 961)
```

Comment: Isn't sorting ~O(n log n) and finding the max O(n) ? - It's better to find the max directly

Comment: Agree, taking the maximum directly is faster and a bit more intuitive.

Comment: But nice to know if you want the top 3 by value of the list...

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the list and keep the tuple in a variable and then you can see both values from the same variable...

```
num=(0, 0)
for item in tuplelist:
  if item[1]>num[1]:
    num=item #num has the whole tuple with the highest y value and its x value
```

Comment: I think `max()` is a lot easier.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah, but that was posted while I was writing my post. I wasn't thinking about that. I'll edit it to not say that anymore, but keep my post just so there is an alternative way to do it for posterity. :)

Comment: what if all the tuples contain negative values? num stays (0,0)

Comment: @Davos can use something like LOWEST_VALUE instead of 0 which stores the lowest value your program is gonna use