# Add probabilities and get id with the highest probability

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
('2', 0.30334973335266113)
('4', 0.43178531527519226)
('3', 0.3627113997936249)
('9', 0.5691161155700684)
('2', 0.4603477120399475)
('2', 0.7340329885482788)
('10', 0.4691111445426941)
('13', 0.20860238373279572)
('3', 0.4541565775871277)
('2', 0.4479588568210602)
('2', 0.6090611815452576)
('16', 0.5154575705528259)
('11', 0.4370063543319702)
('12', 0.38097500801086426)
('14', 0.23826521635055542)
('3', 0.39956724643707275)
('12', 0.291579008102417)
('11', 0.4514589309692383)
```

I want to get an output that adds the probabilities of each of the id there and return the one that has the highest score.

For instance for 3 and 10:

```
(3, 1.2)
(10, 0.46)
```

The return should be: (3, 1.2)

```
summed = {}
lis = [('2', 0.30334973335266113),
('4', 0.43178531527519226),
('3', 0.3627113997936249),
('9', 0.5691161155700684),
('2', 0.4603477120399475),
('2', 0.7340329885482788),
('10', 0.4691111445426941),
('13', 0.20860238373279572),
('3', 0.4541565775871277),
('2', 0.4479588568210602),
('2', 0.6090611815452576),
('16', 0.5154575705528259),
('11', 0.4370063543319702),
('12', 0.38097500801086426),
('14', 0.23826521635055542),
('3', 0.39956724643707275),
('12', 0.291579008102417),
('11', 0.4514589309692383)]

for i in lis:
    summed[str(i[0])] = i[1]
```

This though overrides the keys so only the last seen key and its value gets stored. When inserted a new key I don't want it to be overwritten, I want the value to be added to the existing key.

Comment: And what's preventing you from doing so?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What is your data stored in?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: It's currently computed dynamically each line. Not sure what's the most efficient way to handle this type of data sets, lists, or key value maps

Comment: Show your code and then we can see how to improve it.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to show what you have and ask specific questions step by step when you run into problems. Given your last comment, it appears that you don't have a data structure in mind, much less being at the point of selecting algorithms for it. I would recommend researching your options for data structure (as you've already begun to do), and maybe ask a question about that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the values in a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then get the `most_common(1)`:

```
>>> lst = [('2', 0.30334973335266113),..., ('11', 0.4514589309692383)]
>>> c = collections.Counter()
>>> for x,y in lst: c[x] += y
>>> c.most_common(1)
[('2', 2.554750472307205)]
```

---

About your existing code: You are not actually *summing*, but just overwriting the previous value, if any, with `=`. Intead, you should use `+=` and initialize the value with `0` if it does not exist yet. (`collections.Counter` will do this automatically) Then use `max` to get the max element.

```
for x, y in lis:
    if x not in summed:
        summed[x] = 0
    summed[x] += y
print(max(summed.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```