# Numpy max over only the first element of an array of pairs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array consisting of tuples like below:

```
[[(0.56, 1),(0.25, 4), ...],[(0.11, 9), ...], ...]
```

The second element of each tuple is an index reference. I want to extract the tuple with the highest first value per row. Is there a way to achieve this with numpy max?

One thing I tried is playing around with the axis parameter like below:

```
np.max(my_array, axis=0)
```

But this shuffles around the pairs with the index reference not preserved. E.g. the first row in the above example would show something like `[(0.56,4), ...]` whereas I want it to show `[(0.56,1), ...]`

Comment: Is this helpfull? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: @kabooya I was checking that earlier. I am looking for a solution specifically with numpy vs standard lib, but worth linking still

Comment: Don't use an numpy array of tuples. Convert it just into a numpy array where the last dimension is 2.

Comment: Is there any way you are using tuples instead of arrays?

Comment: When it is converted to a numpy array those tuples are treated as lists. I specified the problem like this to convey the elements are pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain python, you could use :

```
[max(row, key=lambda row: row[0]) for row in array]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tuples in numpy arrays. Convert it all to a numpy array with the last dimension being 2:

```
>>> a = np.array([[(0.56, 1), (0.25, 4)],[(0.11, 9), (0.19, 5)]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 2, 2)
```

Then:

```
>>> highest_val_per_row = np.argmax(a[:,:,0], axis=1)
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), highest_val_per_row]
array([[0.56, 1.  ],
       [0.19, 5.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something linke this:

```
lst = [[(0.56, 1),(0.25, 4)],[(0.11, 9), (0.25, 4)]]

for e in lst: 
    print(max(e))
```

However, i think there are more efficient ways of doing it.