# Finding the max element's index in a Tuple list? (Python)

Tags: python, tuples

I want to find the max element's index in a list of tuple elements so i can reach the key value.
How can i do that?
Basically my code;

```
temp_tuple = [
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 3),
    ('C', 1)
]

max_value = max(value[1] for value in temp_tuple)
```

I want to find *('B',3)* or *1* as index

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only max **tuple value**:

```
max_tuple = max(temp_tuple, key=lambda x:x[1])
print(max_tuple)

>> ('B', 3)
```

if you want **index** of max tuple too:

```
max_tuple = max(temp_tuple, key=lambda x:x[1])
max_tuple_index = temp_tuple.index(max_tuple)
print(max_tuple)
print(max_tuple_index)

>> ('B', 3)
>> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
temp_tuple = [("A", 1), ("B", 3), ("C", 1)]

sorted_temp_tuple = sorted(enumerate(temp_tuple), key=lambda i: i[1][1], reverse=True)
# Result: [(1, ('B', 3)), (0, ('A', 1)), (2, ('C', 1))]

original_index, max_val_item = sorted_temp_tuple[0]

print(max_val_item)
>> ('B', 3)

print(original_index)
>> 1
```

Comment: you marked this question for a dupe, then later give an answer to it, could have left a comment instead

Comment: True, at first I didn't think about OP's request to receive both the value *and* the index.